# ruby Date.month with a leading zero

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have a `Date` object in Ruby.

When I do `myobj.month` I get `8`. How do I get the date's month with a leading zero such as `08`.

Same idea with `day`.

What I am trying to get at the end is `2015/08/05`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you know about http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime ? Exactly  `%d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)`, `>> Time.new(1,2,5).strftime("%d") => "05"`

Comment: Nope, but that looks like a good way to solve my issue indeed. Feel free to write a full answer to get the points.

Comment: You can use `myobj.strftime("%m")` for month. 
for your expected result `myobj.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")`

Refer this doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: I expect the downvotes are because you are asking how one can obtain a `Fixnum` with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the possibility of using a formated string output

Examples:

```
puts sprintf('%02i', 8)
puts '%02i' % 8
```

`%02i` is the format for 2 digits width integer (number) with leading zeros.
Details can be found in the documentation for [sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

In your specific case with a date, you can just use the `Time#strftime` od [`Date#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) method:

```
require 'time'
puts Time.new(2015,8,1).strftime("%m")
```